# I finished writing the code for an Android application, and it was in Python kivy, and while converting it to exe, this problem appeared

Tags: python, android, kivy, windows-installer, kivymd

While converting kivy code to exe, this error appeared at the end

```
Buildozer failed to execute the last command
The error might be hidden in the log above this error
Please read the full log, and search for it before raising an issue with buildozer itself.
In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I tried through Google Colab, all the steps were correct until the last step, this problem appeared and I did not understand it

Comment: The error message suggests that the reason for your build failure may be given inside of your log. Please provide a larger excerpt or even your entire error log. Also: Why are you building an Android app as an .exe-file?